# mounted is being shared across instances of a component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, lifecycle

I have multiple instances of a component being rendered, not at the same time, if you open up a different container, another instance gets rendered. The first instance rendered gets the mounted() triggered but all the other instances don't and they share the same results of that mounted call. How do I separate them? I tried doing "@Watch('prop')" but the first instance of the component doesn't get that method called, since prop hasn't changed.

```
@Prop() assignee!: Person;

accountName = '';

data(): any {
return {
accountName: '',
}
}

async mounted(): Promise<void> {
this.accountName = ...;
}
```

so accountName is the same for different instances of the component, since the mounted call didn't get triggered.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. A problem like that doesn't exist in general. `accountName = ...;` - it would throw because of undefined variable, or you're using global variable that is shared between components indeed, which is a mistake. "since the mounted call didn't get triggered" - how did you confirm this?

Comment: @EstusFlask I updated the question to show that accountName is from the data. and I confirmed that mounted didn't get triggered by putting a break point.

Comment: You use `accountName` and not `this.accountName`. If it differs in real code then again, the example that is able to reproduce the problem is needed